# How to use(or find or modprobe) .ko in modules.builtin

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I tried to  built-in(or modules) in new kernel(used arm-none-linux-gnueabi- and got a new baby zImage & Image),then i flashed new kernel to ARM Board. But nothing did happen. The wierd thing is that I can find (i.e.kernel/drivers/char/hello_module.ko) when I ran "cat modules.builtin" command.

So I think this thing already built in Board , but how can i to use it such that printk someting or register a new device name.

dmesg shows the prinkt messages when i insmod hello_module.ko.So I did do something wrong in  some making new kernel steps. It's really confused me (i.e. i ran commands  like make || make zImage|| make bzImage and make modules make modules_install  after finished the step of make menuconfig) then i flash kernel to Board. But nothing works .

I'm pretty new so i think i feked up some fatal things , any help will be much appreciated.

here's my codes

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init hello_module_init(void)
{
    printk("Hello, this module is installed !\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_module_cleanup(void)
{
    printk("Good-bye, this module was removed!\n");
}

module_init(hello_module_init);
module_exit(hello_module_cleanup);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

[insmod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHTFf.png)

Comment: For builtin your init will be called at boot, then the init code will be freed. The exit code won't be included. Are you not seeing the printk in dmesg?

Comment: @stark  nope. Mate, I think i've been fooled by Board.

Comment: Since you have built it as a module, something or someone has to trigger a loading process  (as you have already noticed by invoking `insmod` manually). For automatic load you need either build it in, or create a script that will `insmod` it for you.